# Combining rasters after weighted overlay

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, weighted-overlay

I have performed five weighted overlay analyses in arcgis 10.2 and got five rasters with pixel values ranging from 1 to 10 as outputs. Now I need to combine those rasters in one single raster stating layer name which is having maximum dominance for each pixel. Cell statistics will only give the actual maximum pixel value among several input rasters, but I need to identify raster 'file name' which is having maximum value, for each pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to be using the [highest position](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/highest-position.htm) tool? You can then decode the number to identify the raster name as you know what order you provided the rasters in.